# Monitoring changes in database Linq

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

```
        try
        {
            var dda = db.Contacts.Where(b => b.indecator == g.UserIndecator()).SingleOrDefault();

            req = Convert.ToString(dda.status);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( е + "Error of request");
        }

        return req;
```

The problem is that with every request I get the same values.

Only by calling `Application.Restart();` I can get a new value. How to fix it?

g.UserIndecator () == "abc123";   // static string

dda.status == 1 || 0;             // int

Comment: What is `g` and what does `g.UserIndecator()` return? I assume some sort of Id...

Comment: This code looks almost fine - there is no obvious reason that this should return stall data. (Almost because I would expect that you get a runtime exception because `b.indecator == g.UserIndecator()` does not look like it is translatable to SQL - what are the (return) types of `g`, `g.UserIndecator()` and `db`?)

Comment: please post how you create db

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that your data context (db) is not being recreated on each iteration of your check, therefore you are getting cached data.